# What happens to my FTL progress when I quit during combat?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

In FTL, the "Save & Quit" options is disabled during combat. If I am in the middle of a battle and have to quit, will I lose all my progress, or can I still continue from some recent point, like right before the battle started?

Comment: Rather than editing the question, you should put that information in a new answer, and move the checkmark over to it.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that... Actually, the new version really does invalidate the premise of the question. The first sentence is no longer true. Should I still just add a new answer and accept it?

Comment: Yes; it preserves the question and answers for historical/archival purposes, in case someone's using an older version of the game somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest version of FTL adds the ability to save at any time, so the new answer is that yes, your progress is always saved, even if you quit during a fight or some other danger.

Answer (score 19):

If you quit the game your data will not be saved, you'll need to start over from the beginning. Source: tested it in game.

Comment: I can confirm this. Also tested it myself, 30 seconds later.

Comment: This kind of lame. Sometimes I need to quit on short notice, and it's very possible to pass through several jump points in a row without reaching a point where one can save.

Comment: +RyanThompson, welcome to roguelikes

Comment: @RyanThompson You can always save after winning a battle. If you continue jumping out of battle, you're out of luck - though that will like prevent you from obtaining enough scraps to upgrade your ship anyway...

Comment: No you can't always save after a battle. You can't save in an asteroid field, near a sun, etc, even after you win the battle.

Answer (score 7):

Your save and quit is a one shot deal. It works by writing your current game data to a file called continue.sav in your FTL directory.

This file only exists if you do "Save & Quit" from the menu. As soon as you load up your game and continue your quest, your data is loaded and the file is immediately deleted. So any interruption in the application, like quitting in a battle, while playing before another "quit & save" will result in a permanently lost quest.

You could always back up continue.sav, but this is considered cheating by many and not the intent of the developers. But it's your game, do as you wish.